# Copying from unmanaged memory to multidimensional array (and vice versa)

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to read an image into a three-dimensional array. Something like this:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("testImage.png");
BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);
byte[,,] image = new byte[bmp.Height, bmp.Width, 4];

Marshal.PtrToStructure(bmpData.Scan0, image);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(image, bmpData.Scan0, false);

bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
bmp.Save("testImageOut.png");
```

But this throws me an error `The specified structure must be blittable or have layout information.`

Any idea how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Where is the unmanaged memory coming from ?  It looks like you are just copying bmpData to the image array.  I think you just need to create binary serialize data of the bmpData.

Comment: bmpData just contains information about where the bitmap is in the memory, such as the starting address, stride, etc. It doesn't actually hold any of the bytes of the image.

Comment: So it looks like you are trying to take the header data from the bmp image and store in bmpData.

Comment: This is not where the problem arises. Locking the image into memory works, but I can't just copy the bits from the memory to the multidimensional array in this way.

Comment: I though you said the bmpData only was a pointer to memory where the starts and not the data.